# How do I get a list of running processes remotely?

Tags: delphi, process

How do i get list of the running processes on some other machine (over the network) using Delphi?

Comment: What have you thought of or tried already?

Comment: Please elaborate and show some source... what is the OS of the other machine (Unix, Linux, OSX, Windows...) ? what sort of network access do you have (WAN/LAN...) ? Are there any firewalls etc. inbetween ? what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: Check the link here for the details code [Get the list of active process on a PC of my network?](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2112)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394572%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Class.

Check this sample

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  SysUtils,
  ActiveX,
  ComObj,
  Variants;


procedure  GetWin32_ProcessInfo;
const
  WbemUser            ='';//set the user name to log in
  WbemPassword        ='';//set the password
  WbemComputer        ='localhost';//set the name of the remote machine or IP address
  wbemFlagForwardOnly = $00000020;
var
  FSWbemLocator : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService   : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet: OLEVariant;
  FWbemObject   : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;
begin;
  FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  FWMIService   := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemComputer, 'root\CIMV2', WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  FWbemObjectSet:= FWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Process','WQL',wbemFlagForwardOnly);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(FWbemObjectSet._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  while oEnum.Next(1, FWbemObject, iValue) = 0 do
  begin
    Writeln(Format('Name         %s',[String(FWbemObject.Name)]));// String
    Writeln(Format('ProcessId    %d',[Integer(FWbemObject.ProcessId)]));// Uint32
    Writeln;
    FWbemObject:=Unassigned;
  end;
end;


begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_ProcessInfo;
    finally
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:EOleException do
        Writeln(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ':', E.Message);
 end;
 Writeln('Press Enter to exit');
 Readln;
end.
```

In order to work with the WMI in a remote machine you must set the firewall and DCOM settings check these articles for more info .

- [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting Through Windows Firewall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389286%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Securing a Remote WMI Connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Connecting Between Different Operating Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Now i have another question ... hot to kill process over network? Thnx :))

Answer (score 0):

See the EnumProcesses procedure from the TlHelp32 unit.

Comment: EnumProcesses doesn't work across machine boundaries, does it?

Comment: No. You would need to write a separate program that runs on the remote machine, then it can enumerate the local processes of that machine and make that list accessible to remote apps.

Comment: @Remy: That's why I asked. I wondered if Stijn knew something I didn't about EnumProcesses, since the question is specifically about "some other machine (over the network)".

Comment: tss, I shouldn't post past midnight, I entirely missed the 'over the network' bit... too bad these aren't open source though: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649