# Killing running processes on some other machine (over the network) using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, networking, process, kill

How can i kill running process on some other machine (over the network) using Delphi?

Comment: Modify the RRUZ's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7947091/960757) ; just change the WQL query to `SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = TheProcessNameYouWantToKill` and call FWbemObject.Terminate.

Comment: I would like to do it in delphi and not using command prompt ;)

Comment: @DVDavy Either with WMI as suggested above or `CreateProcess` to `taskkill /s` for the quick win!

Comment: I did it with WMI :)) Thnx ;)

Answer (score 9):

Everything you need can be found at [The Road to Delphi](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/), he just blog'd about how to do this on November 6th, check this link [`WMI Tasks using Delphi – Processes`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/wmi-tasks-using-delphi-%E2%80%93-processes/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WTSTerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383846%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API or use [Jwscl](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/) (Windows Security Library) [Terminal Server unit](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/JwsclTerminalServer_pas.html) (the [TJwWTSProcess](http://jwscldoc.delphi-jedi.net/index.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TJwWTSProcess.html) class offers a Terminate method).

Small code example:

```
var 
  TS: TJwTerminalServer;
begin
  TS := TJwTerminalServer.Create('Remote');
  try
    if TS.EnumerateProcess then
    begin
      for i := 0 to TS.Processes.Count -1 do
      begin
        if TS.Processes[i].Name = 'notepad.exe' then
        begin
           TS.Processes[i].Terminate;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    TS.Free;
  end;
end;
```